# How to store doc,xls,pdf,image.xml files in windows application using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

i want to store files in my sql server 2008 database.

I am still confusing how to do it and what datatype i have to take to store any file in my database.

Any one have idea about this please help me...

Thanks,
Balu

Comment: asked many times on SO: try reading http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2007/05/save-and-restore-filesimages-to-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in binary and use full text search to interpret the binary data and extract the textual information: .doc, .txt, .xls, .ppt, .htm. The extracted text is indexed and becomes available for querying.

For more information look at this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142499(SQL.90).aspx

Pros: The main advantage of storing data in the database is that it makes the data "self-contained". Since all of the data is contained within the database, backing up the data, moving the data from one database server to another, replicating the database, and so on, is much easier.

also you can enable versioning of files and also make it easier for load balanced web farms.

Cons: you can read it here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/sql-server-2005-large-binary-storage. But this is something that you have to do in order to search through the files efficiently.

Or the other thing that I could suggest is probably storing keywords in the database and then linking the same to file in the fileshare.

Here is an article discussing abt using a FileStream and a database: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manisblog/archive/2007/10/21/filestream-data-type-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The datatype is - `VARBINARY(MAX)`

Storing files in database has its advantages and dis-advantages:

If the files are integral and actively changing part of the system and them have to be backed up along with the other data - you can store them inside the DB, **but** try to use the `FILESTREAM` fields if you use sql server 2005+ and your files are big enough - say 500k+

If the files are static content, you can store them outside with only pointers in DB. This not prevents to take into account all your custom permissions machine.

Storing and working with files inside DB is usually slower, than in filesystem, but all depends on your needs.

**PROPER** using of filestream is **NOT** slower than using filesystem, the DB is little slower when you store files in pure `varbinary(max)` columns